# php header to localhost url automatically adding port numbers

Tags: php, localhost

I am trying to test out some simple functionality using a local server. I am trying to redirect from one url on the server to another but am having some issues with it automatically reformatting my url. I've tried a few different variations but all of them end up doing something I don't want.

I am starting at the url `localhost/wordpress/demo.php` where demo.php contains the redirect, and I am trying to go to `localhost/otherDirectory`

The things I've tried:

```
    header('Location:localhost/otherDirectory');
    //Goes to: localhost/wordpress/localhost/otherDirectory

    header('Location:https://localhost/otherDirectory');
    //Goes to: the correct link, but this test server doesn't use https

    header('Location:http://localhost/otherDirectory');
    //Goes to: localhost:8080/otherDirectory
    //         this is wrong, I'm not sure where the port number
    //         is coming from but it makes it unusable

    header('Location:/otherDirectory');
    //Goes to: Exact same as previous
```

What is the correct way to do this? I'm not sure why its adding the port number or even why that port number would screw anything up (I'm pretty sure im using 8080 already). Im using WAMP btw if thats relevent.

Comment: did you try to use php.ini or .htaccess to do the redirection ? In normal cases this will not insert the port number to your target redirected URL

Answer (score 0):

First off try using double quotes in your header or...

For Wordpress use their redirect built-in function

```
wp_redirect( "http://localhost/otherDirectory", 301 );
```